# How to modify the attachment info text on gallery tab or media page?

Tags: media-library

when show/edit an image/file, on the right side of the image/file, there are some text info-- File name, File Type, Upload date, Demention... How to modify those text?

Comment: what you mean by modify? alter them? or add new ones, delete them? I'm not new in attachment field so maybe i can post answer but i need to know what exacly you want to do. and exacly what fields if you want to edit them.

Comment: @Tommix , it's not fields, it's the area on the top left of the edit image screen.  currently it's File Nmae, File Type, Uplaod date. I want to change it to Title, Author, Source, License.

Comment: So you want to ADD new fields,labels, not change. If you only want change words you can do that via translating them but it's stupid you need add new fields, labels. Wait i'll show you how. As i understood you want to asign value to those fields by yourself dynamicly so it shouldn't be editable yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to functions.php file.

```
  function image_attachment_field($form_fields, $post) {  
if( substr($post->post_mime_type, 0, 5) == 'image' ){  
    $user = new WP_User( $post->post_author );
    $form_fields["author"]["input"] = "html"; 
    $form_fields["author"]["html"] = '<p><strong>Author:</strong> '.$user->display_name.'</p>';
    $form_fields["license"]["input"] = "html"; 
    $form_fields["license"]["html"] = '<p><strong>License:</strong> GPL</p>';
    $form_fields["source"]["input"] = "html"; 
    $form_fields["source"]["html"] = '<p><strong>Source:</strong> BNS</p>';

}
    return $form_fields;  
}  

add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "image_attachment_field", null, 2);
```

This will ONLY add info, cause you did not said you want user be able to edit it. So you have to edit this code to asign values.

Also there is no easy way of putting these labels in top. So don't ask me how, it just did not possible to do without editing WP code or adding javascript to change possitions of elements, but this also is not very wise.

Comment: That's exactly what I want-- provide media info and not allow editing. Thanks! It'd be better if can remove the file type / file name on the right side of picture, but since you said it's not easy without modify core, I will live with that.

Comment: yep - you can't hide them without editing core or withouth useing jQuery to hide those elements, but in both cases - custom labels still be putted lower then those in top so...no easy way to do this if you still want to use WP updates.